# How to turn off Magit default switch (--reset-author in Commit)

Tags: magit

I did something causing the -R (--reset-author) switch in the Commit menu to always be on by default. How can I reset this?

Comment: Is it still on if you restart your Emacs? You could toggle it by type `- R` in case you don't know that yet.

Comment: I had tried - R. It did toggle, but switch would be back on again the next time I committed.

I now tried restarting Emacs. That fixed the problem.  Thanks!|

(any idea why this happened? I'm not used to that kind of weird statefulness in Emacs; it's been a long time since I last had to restart).

Comment: I think that's because you somehow set `magit-commit-arguments`, and I've posted it as an answer, please have a check if it helps :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with other Magit popups, set the flags the way you want them to be by default, and type <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>.

(n.b. This is likely how you got into that situation in the first place.)

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `magit-popup-set-default-arguments`

(or type <kbd>?</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> in the popup buffer.)

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your problem by setting (default is `nil` ):

```
(setq magit-commit-arguments '("--reset-author"))
```

So check this variable in your config, and remove `"--reset-author"` from it.